# Modifying DataView thread safety

Tags: multithreading, ado.net, datatable, thread-safety, dataview

I am parallelizing some of my code, and in this section, I have DataViews accessing a common DataTable. There are places where I modify the DataViews, but in necessarily discrete records among the threads. Do I still need to institute Semaphores for these modifications (not row addition/deletions, but only mods), if I know that specific records won't be touched simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I went ahead and tried implementing the solution as if that were true, and a `DataTable` is very **not** thread-safe.  *e.g.* Modifying one record and creating a new (unrelated) `DataView` at the same time will result in an Exception.  A good learning exercise, I suppose.